Applying a summation method to two sums. I need to justify an interchange of summation and integration with this method. Is my use of Fubini flawed?
Below I obtain the Leibniz formula for $\pi$ using a particular summation method. However, you need to justify a step where you interchange a summation and integration. Fubini would not work here. So I'm using the dominated convergence theorem. Is this approach correct?
I then apply the same method of summation to the sum:
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^2}
\end{align*}
for $0 < x < 1$ with expected result of $\pi^2 (x^2-x+\frac{1}{6})$. Interchanging summation and integration seem valid using Fubini, but then the end result of the calculation does not seem yield the expected results - it diverges. I am a bit new to Fubini and I think maybe my use of it is flawed.
MAJOUR EDIT: According to wolfram the integral in my formula:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^2} & = \frac{1}{2} Re \int_0^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u u^2}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\end{align*}
(which I derive below) converges for all values of $x$ I've tried! Moreover, we have agreement with the expected result: $\pi^2 (x^2-x+\frac{1}{6})$ for these values of $x$!
So the question is then, why do get a divergent result when I attempt to evaluate the integral using a complex contour integration (see below)? How do you perform the integral?
FIRST SUM I WANT TO EVALUATE:
Here is how I obtained the Leibniz formula for $\pi$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\sin \dfrac{\pi n}{2}}{n}
\nonumber \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\sin \dfrac{\pi n}{2}}{n} \int_0^\infty e^{-y} dy
\nonumber \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin \dfrac{\pi n}{2} \int_0^\infty e^{-nx} dx
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2i} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty (e^{-nx + \frac{i\pi n}{2}} - e^{-nx + \frac{-i\pi n}{2}}) dx
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2i} \int_0^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty (e^{-nx + \frac{i\pi n}{2}} - e^{-nx + \frac{-i\pi n}{2}}) dx
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2i} \int_0^\infty \left( \dfrac{1}{1-e^{-x + \frac{i\pi}{2}}} - \dfrac{1}{1-e^{-x + \frac{-i\pi}{2}}} \right) dx
\nonumber \\
& = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{1}  {e^x + e^{-x}} dx
\end{align*}
You can use the fact that $\frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1} (\sinh x) = \frac{1}{\cosh x}$ to obtain:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{2}{e^x + e^{-x}} dx = \frac{1}{2} [\tan^{-1} (\sinh x)]_0^\infty = \frac{\pi}{4}  .
\end{align*}
Note in the above, I made an interchange of summation and integration. This needs to be justified.
Fubini can't be applied:
As
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty \left| \sin \dfrac{\pi n}{2} e^{-nx} \right| dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2n+1} = \infty
\end{align*}
you can't use Fubini to justify this interchange. An equivalent check?:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left| \sin \dfrac{\pi n}{2} e^{-nx} \right| dx & = \int_0^\infty (e^{-x} + e^{-3x} + e^{-5x} + \cdots) dx
\nonumber \\
& = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{e^x-e^{-x}} dx
\nonumber \\
& = \left[ \frac{1}{2} \ln \left( \dfrac{e^{x/2} - e^{-x/2}}{e^{x/2} + e^{-x/2}} \right) \right]_0^\infty = \infty
\end{align*}
Using the dominated convergence theorem:
I now justify interchanging summation and integration using the dominated convergence theorem. Define $f_N (x) = \sum_{n=1}^N \sin \dfrac{\pi n}{2} e^{-nx}$. Then, for appropriate integers $\ell,\ell'$ taken from $1,2, \cdots$, we have
\begin{align*}
f_N (x) & = 
\begin{cases}
e^{-x} - e^{-3x} + e^{-5x} - e^{-7x} + \cdots + e^{-(4\ell-3)x} & \text{ odd number of terms} \\
e^{-x} - e^{-3x} + e^{-5x} - e^{-7x} + \cdots - e^{-(4\ell'-1)x} & \text{ even number of terms} \\
   \end{cases}
\nonumber \\
& = 
\begin{cases}
e^{-x} \dfrac{1+e^{-(4\ell-1)x}}{1+e^{-2x}} & \text{ odd number of terms} \\
e^{-x} \dfrac{1-e^{-(4\ell'+1)x}}{1+e^{-2x}} & \text{ even number of terms} \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
So the limit function for $x > 0$ is
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} f_N(x) = f(x) = \dfrac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}}
\end{align*}
So $f_N(x)$ converges to the function $f(x)$ except at $x=0$:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} |f(x) - f_N (x)| & = 
\begin{cases}
\lim_{\ell \rightarrow \infty} e^{-x} \dfrac{e^{-(4\ell-1)x}}{1+e^{-2x}} = 0 & \text{ odd number of terms} \\
\lim_{\ell' \rightarrow \infty} e^{-x} \dfrac{e^{-(4\ell'+1)x}}{1+e^{-2x}} = 0 & \text{ even number of terms} \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
It is not a problem that you don't have convergence at the single point $x=0$?
Also,
\begin{align*}
0 \leq f_N (x)\leq \dfrac{1+e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}} e^{-x} = e^{-x}
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
|f_N (x)| \leq e^{-x} = g(x)
\end{align*}
The function $g(x)$ is integrable. By the dominated convergence theorem
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\infty \sum_{n=1}^N \sin \dfrac{\pi n}{2} e^{-nx} dx = \int_0^\infty \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \sin \dfrac{\pi n}{2} e^{-nx} dx
\end{align*}
SECOND SUM I WANT TO EVALUATE:
We have:
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^2}
\nonumber \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^2} \int_0^\infty u e^{-u} du
\nonumber \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos (2 \pi n x) \int_0^\infty u e^{-nu} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty (e^{-nu + i n 2 \pi x} + e^{-nu - i n 2 \pi x}) u du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty (e^{-nu + i n 2 \pi x} + e^{-nu - i n 2 \pi x}) u du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \left( \dfrac{1}{e^{u - 2 \pi x i} - 1} + \dfrac{1}{e^{u + 2 \pi x i} - 1} \right) u du
\end{align*}
To justify interchanging summation and integration in  the above, I appeal to Fubini:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty | \cos (2 \pi n x)u e^{-nu} | du & \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty u e^{-nu} du
\nonumber \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}  < \infty
\end{align*}
Continuing from where I left off above
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^2} & = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \left( \dfrac{1}{e^{u - 2 \pi x i} - 1} + \dfrac{1}{e^{u + 2 \pi x i} - 1} \right) u du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \left( \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} u}{e^u - e^{2 \pi x i}} + \dfrac{e^{-2 \pi x i} u}{e^u - e^{-2 \pi x i}} \right) du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{4} \int_0^\infty \left( \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u u^2}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} + \dfrac{e^{-2 \pi x i} e^u u^2}{(e^u - e^{-2 \pi x i})^2} \right) du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{8} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u u^2}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} + \dfrac{e^{-2 \pi x i} e^u u^2}{(e^u - e^{-2 \pi x i})^2} \right) du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{4} Re \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u u^2}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\end{align*}
where I have done an integration by parts. Extending the range of integration in the second to last step is valid if you use both terms. Define
\begin{align*}
I (\alpha) = \frac{1}{4} e^{2 \pi x i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{\alpha u}}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\end{align*}
for $\frac{1}{2} \leq \alpha \leq \frac{3}{2}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^2} = \left. \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial \alpha^2} Re I (\alpha) \right|_{\alpha =1}
\end{align*}
In order to evaluate $I(\alpha)$, consider the contour in the figure.

The integral along the vertical edges vanishes as:
\begin{align*}
f(z) = \dfrac{e^{\alpha (u+iv)}}{(e^{u+iv} + e^{2 \pi x i})^2} =
\begin{cases}
      e^{(\alpha - 2) (u+iv)} & u \rightarrow \infty \\
      e^{\alpha (u+iv)}  & u \rightarrow - \infty \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
So that
\begin{align*}
& \frac{1}{4} e^{2 \pi x i} \oint_C \dfrac{e^{\alpha z}}{(e^z - e^{2 \pi x i})^2}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{4} e^{2 \pi x i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{\alpha u}}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du - \frac{1}{4} e^{2 \pi x i} e^{\alpha 2 \pi i} \int_{-\infty + 2 \pi i}^{\infty + 2 \pi i} \dfrac{e^{\alpha u}}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = (1-e^{\alpha 2 \pi i}) \frac{1}{4} e^{2 \pi x i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{\alpha u}}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\end{align*}
So that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{4} e^{2 \pi x i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{\alpha u}}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du & = \frac{i}{2} \frac{e^{2 \pi x i}}{1-e^{\alpha 2 \pi i}} \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \dfrac{e^{\alpha z}}{(e^z - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} dz
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{i}{2} \frac{e^{2 \pi x i}}{1-e^{\alpha 2 \pi i}} Res [f(z)]
\end{align*}
We have
\begin{align*}
(e^z - e^{z_0})^2 & = (e^{z_0 + (z-z_0)} - e^{z_0})^2
\nonumber \\
& = (e^{z_0} [ 1 + (z-z_0) + \frac{1}{2!} (z-z_0)^2 + \cdots] - e^{z_0})^2
\nonumber \\
& = e^{2 z_0} (z-z_0)^2 (1 + \frac{1}{2!} (z-z_0) + \cdots)^2
\end{align*}
where $z_0$ is the singular point. So that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(e^z - e^{z_0})^2} & = \dfrac{e^{-2 z_0}}{(z-z_0)^2 [1 + \frac{1}{2!} (z-z_0) + \cdots]^2}
\nonumber \\
& = \dfrac{e^{-2z_0}}{(z-z_0)^2} [1 - (z-z_0) + \cdots]
\nonumber \\
& = \dfrac{e^{-2z_0}}{(z-z_0)^2} - \dfrac{e^{-2z_0}}{z-z_0} + \cdots
\end{align*}
which we use to extract the residue of $f(z)$. Combining everything
\begin{align*}
I(\alpha) & = \frac{1}{4} e^{2 \pi x i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{\alpha u}}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{i}{2} e^{2 \pi x i} \frac{1}{1-e^{\alpha 2 \pi i}} (- e^{- 4 \pi x i} e^{\alpha 2 \pi x i})
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{4} e^{-2 \pi x (1 - \alpha) i - \alpha \pi i} \frac{2i}{e^{\alpha \pi i} - e^{-\alpha \pi i}}
\end{align*}
So that
\begin{align*}
Re I(\alpha) & = \frac{1}{4} \frac{ \cos [2 \pi x (1 - \alpha ) + \alpha \pi]}{\sin \alpha \pi}
\end{align*}
However, taking the second derivative w.r.t $\alpha$ and then putting $\alpha=1$ will result in a divergence! Is my use of Fubini flawed?

I should have been a bit more careful when calculating residues of 2nd order poles. This is where it went wrong.
I provide three methods to obtain the answer. Method I: I define my $I(\alpha)$ slightly differently than in my question. I calculate $I (\alpha)$ using the same contour integral method as employed in the question. I then Taylor expand $I(\alpha)$ and read off the coefficient of $\alpha^2$ (you can differentiate $I(\alpha)$ twice with respect to $\alpha$ and take the limit $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ but it is a bit messy).
Method II: I calculate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^{u} u^2}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du$ by considering a couple of complex contour integrals.
Method III: The method used in the question can be used to evaluate the general Fourier series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^{2k}}
\end{align*}
for $k=1,2,\dots$ with the result being proportional to the Bernoulli polynomial $B_{2k} (x)$, as $I(\alpha)$ is directly related to the generating function for Bernoulli polynomials. There is an explicit expression for Bernoulli polynomials in terms of Bernoulli numbers, which can be easily obtained using their respective generating functions. Using generating functions makes extracting the answer fairly easy. I obtain the expression for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^2}$ this way.
METHOD I
Define
\begin{align*}
I (\alpha) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^{\alpha u} e^u}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\end{align*}
for $-\frac{1}{2} \leq \alpha \leq \frac{1}{2}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^2} = \frac{1}{4} \left. \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial \alpha^2} Re I (\alpha) \right|_{\alpha =0}  \qquad  (*)  .
\end{align*}
In order to evaluate $I(\alpha)$, consider the contour in the figure

and the integral
\begin{align*}
\oint_C \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^{\alpha z} e^z}{(e^z - e^{2 \pi x i})^2}
\end{align*}
whose integrand has pole at $2 \pi x i$. The integral along the vertical edges vanishes, and by following the same steps as in the question, we arrive a
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^{\alpha u} e^u}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du & = \frac{2 \pi i }{1-e^{\alpha 2 \pi i}} \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^{\alpha z} e^z}{(e^z - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} dz
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{2 \pi i}{1-e^{\alpha 2 \pi i}} Res [f(z)]
\end{align*}
We wish to expand the integrand in powers of $z-z_0$ about pole $z_0= 2\pi x i$. First note:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(e^z - e^{z_0})^2} & = \frac{e^{-2 z_0}}{(e^{z-z_0} - 1)^2}
\nonumber \\
& = \dfrac{e^{-2z_0}}{(z-z_0)^2} - \dfrac{e^{-2z_0}}{z-z_0} + \cdots
\end{align*}
Then note:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{e^{z_0} e^{\alpha z} e^z}{(e^z - e^{z_0})^2} & = e^{-z_0}  \dfrac{ e^{(\alpha + 1) z_0 + (\alpha + 1) (z-z_0)} }{ (z-z_0)^2 } - e^{-z_0} \dfrac{ e^{(\alpha + 1) z_0} }{ z-z_0 } + \cdots
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-z_0} \dfrac{ e^{(\alpha + 1) z_0} [1 + (\alpha + 1) (z-z_0) + \cdots] }{ (z-z_0)^2 } - e^{-z_0} \dfrac{ e^{(\alpha + 1) z_0} }{ z-z_0 } + \cdots
\nonumber \\
& = \dfrac{ e^{\alpha z_0} }{ (z-z_0)^2 } + \dfrac{ \alpha e^{\alpha z_0} }{ z-z_0 } + \cdots
\end{align*}
Combining everything
\begin{align*}
I(\alpha) & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^{\alpha u}}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = 2 \pi i \frac{1}{1-e^{\alpha 2 \pi i}} \cdot \alpha e^{\alpha 2 \pi x i}
\nonumber \\
& = - e^{\alpha 2 \pi x i - \alpha \pi i} \dfrac{\alpha \pi}{\sin \alpha \pi}
\end{align*}
Taylor expanding $I (\alpha)$ to get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos 2 \pi x}{n^2}$
We Taylor expand $I(\alpha)$:
\begin{align*}
I(\alpha) & = - e^{\alpha 2 \pi x i - \alpha \pi i} \dfrac{\alpha \pi}{\sin \alpha \pi}
\nonumber \\
& = - \left[ 1 + \alpha \pi i (2x-1) - \frac{1}{2} \alpha^2 \pi^2 (2x-1)^2 + \cdots \right] \dfrac{1}{1 - \dfrac{1}{3!} \alpha^2 \pi^2 + \cdots}
\nonumber \\
& = - \left[ 1 + \alpha \pi i (2x-1) - \frac{1}{2} \alpha^2 \pi^2 (2x-1)^2 + \cdots \right] \left[ 1 + \dfrac{1}{6} \alpha^2 \pi^2 + \cdots \right]
\nonumber \\
& = - \left[ 1 + \alpha \pi i (2x-1) - \frac{1}{2} \alpha^2 \pi^2 (2x-1)^2 + \dfrac{1}{6} \alpha^2 \pi^2 + \cdots \right]
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\left. \frac{1}{4} \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial \alpha^2} I(\alpha) \right|_{\alpha=0} & = \pi^2 \left( x-\frac{1}{2} \right)^2 - \dfrac{\pi^2}{12}
\nonumber \\
& = \pi^2 \left( x^2 - x + \frac{1}{6} \right)
\end{align*}
and substituting this into $(*)$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^2} = \pi^2 \left( x^2 - x + \frac{1}{6} \right)  .
\end{align*}
METHOD II
We use the same rectangular contour as in method I. In the two complex contour integrals considered here, the integral along the vertical edges vanishes.
We have
\begin{align*}
\oint_C \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^z z^3}{(e^z - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} dz & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u u^3}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du - \int_{-\infty+2 \pi i}^{\infty + 2 \pi i} \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u (u+ 2 \pi i)^3}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u (3 u^2 (2 \pi i) + 3u (2 \pi i)^2 + (2\pi i)^3)}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = - 3 (2 \pi i) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} u^2 e^u}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du - 3 (2 \pi i)^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} u e^u}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& - (2 \pi i)^3 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& - 3 (2 \pi i) I_2 - 3 (2 \pi i)^2 I_1 - (2 \pi i)^3 I_0
\end{align*}
So that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^z z^3}{(e^z - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} dz = - 3 I_2 - 3 (2 \pi i) I_1 - (2 \pi i)^2 I_0
\end{align*}
The integral $I_0$ is straightforward to do:
\begin{align*}
I_0 & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( - \frac{d}{du} \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i}}{e^u - e^{2 \pi x i}} \right) du
\nonumber \\
& = \left[ - \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i}}{e^u - e^{2 \pi x i}} \right]_{-\infty}^\infty = - 1
\end{align*}
We have the following residue (see below for details)
\begin{align*}
\text{Res}_{z = 2 \pi x i}  \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^z z^3}{(e^z - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} = - 12 \pi^2 x^2 = - 3 I_2 - 3 (2 \pi i) I_1 - (2 \pi i)^2 I_0
\end{align*}
We have
\begin{align*}
\oint_C \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^z z^2}{(e^z - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} dz & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u u^2}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du - \int_{-\infty+2 \pi i}^{\infty + 2 \pi i} \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u (u+ 2 \pi i)^2}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u (2 u (2 \pi i) + (2\pi i)^2}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = - 2 (2 \pi i) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} u e^u}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du - (2 \pi i)^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& - 2 (2 \pi i) I_1 + (2 \pi i)^2
\end{align*}
So that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^z z^2}{(e^z - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} dz = - 2 I_1 + (2 \pi i)
\end{align*}
We have the following residue
\begin{align*}
\text{Res}_{z = 2 \pi x i}  \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^z z^2}{(e^z - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} = i 4 \pi x = - 2 I_1 + (2 \pi i)
\end{align*}
Collecting results
\begin{align*}
- 12 \pi^2 x^2 & = - 3 I_2 - 3 (2 \pi i) I_1 + (2 \pi i)^2
\nonumber \\
i 2 \pi x & = - I_1 + \pi i
\end{align*}
So that
\begin{align*}
I_2 & = 4 \pi^2 x^2 - 2 \pi i I_1 - \frac{4}{3} \pi^2
\nonumber \\
& = 4 \pi^2 x^2 - 2 \pi i (- i 2 \pi x + \pi i) - \frac{4}{3} \pi^2
\nonumber \\
& = 4 \pi^2 \left( x^2 - x + \frac{1}{6} \right)  .
\end{align*}
So finally,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^2} & = \frac{1}{4} Re \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u u^2}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{4} Re I_2
\nonumber \\
& = \pi^2 \left( x^2 - x + \frac{1}{6} \right)  .
\end{align*}
Calculating residues
We calculate
\begin{align*}
\text{Res}_{z = 2 \pi x i}  \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^z z^k}{(e^z - e^{2 \pi x i})^2}  .
\end{align*}
Again,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(e^z - e^{z_0})^2} = \dfrac{e^{-2z_0}}{(z-z_0)^2} - \dfrac{e^{-2z_0}}{z-z_0} + \cdots
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
\frac{e^{z_0} e^z z^k}{(e^z - e^{z_0})^2} & = \frac{e^{2z_0} e^{z-z_0} [z_0 +(z-z_0)]^k}{(e^z - e^{z_0})^2}
\nonumber \\
& = \dfrac{[1 + (z-z_0) + \cdots] [z_0^k + kz_0^{k-1} (z-z_0) + \cdots]}{(z-z_0)^2} - \dfrac{z_0^k}{z-z_0} + \cdots
\nonumber \\
& = \dfrac{z_0^k}{(z-z_0)^2} + \dfrac{kz_0^{k-1}}{z-z_0} + \cdots
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
\text{Res}_{z = 2 \pi x i}  \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^z z^k}{(e^z - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} & = k (2 \pi x i)^{k-1}
\nonumber \\
& = i^{k-1} 2^{k-1} k \pi^{k-1} x^{k-1}  .
\end{align*}
METHOD III
We have:
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^{2k}}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{(2k-1)!} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^{2k}} \int_0^\infty u^{2k-1} e^{-u} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{(2k-1)!} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos (2 \pi n x) \int_0^\infty u^{2k-1} e^{-nu} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{(2k-1)!} \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty (e^{-nu + i n 2 \pi x} + e^{-nu - i n 2 \pi x}) u^{2k-1} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2 (2k-1)!} \int_0^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty (e^{-nu + i n 2 \pi x} + e^{-nu - i n 2 \pi x}) u^{2k-1} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2 (2k-1)!} \int_0^\infty \left( \dfrac{1}{e^{u - 2 \pi x i} - 1} + \dfrac{1}{e^{u + 2 \pi x i} - 1} \right) u^{2k-1} du
\end{align*}
To justify interchanging summation and integration in  the above, we can use Fubini:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(2k-1)!} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty | \cos (2 \pi n x) u^{2k-1} e^{-nu} | du & \leq \frac{1}{(2k-1)!} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty u^{2k-1} e^{-nu} du
\nonumber \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2k}}
\nonumber \\
& < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
\nonumber \\
& < 1 + \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n (n-1)}
\nonumber \\
& = 1 + \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=2}^N \left( \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n} \right)
\nonumber \\
& = 1 + 1 - \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} = 2 < \infty
\end{align*}
From the above
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^{2k}} & = \frac{1}{2 (2k-1)!} \int_0^\infty \left( \dfrac{1}{e^{u - 2 \pi x i} - 1} + \dfrac{1}{e^{u + 2 \pi x i} - 1} \right) u^{2k-1} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2 (2k-1)!} \int_0^\infty \left( \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} u^{2k-1}}{e^u - e^{2 \pi x i}} + \dfrac{e^{-2 \pi x i} u^{2k-1}}{e^u - e^{-2 \pi x i}} \right) du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2 (2k)!} \int_0^\infty \left( \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u u^{2k}}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} + \dfrac{e^{-2 \pi x i} e^u u^{2k}}{(e^u - e^{-2 \pi x i})^2} \right) du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{4 (2k)!} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u u^{2k}}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} + \dfrac{e^{-2 \pi x i} e^u u^{2k}}{(e^u - e^{-2 \pi x i})^2} \right) du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{2 (2k)!} Re \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^u u^{2k}}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\end{align*}
where I done an integration by parts. Extending the range of integration is valid if you use both terms.
Take again
\begin{align*}
I (\alpha) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{2 \pi x i} e^{\alpha u} e^u}{(e^u - e^{2 \pi x i})^2} du
\end{align*}
for $-\frac{1}{2} \leq \alpha \leq \frac{1}{2}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^{2k}} = \frac{1}{2 (2k)!} \left. \dfrac{\partial^{2k}}{\partial \alpha^{2k}} Re I (\alpha) \right|_{\alpha =0}  \qquad  (**)  .
\end{align*}
where, as we have shown in method I,
\begin{align*}
I(\alpha) =  - e^{\alpha 2 \pi x i - \alpha \pi i} \dfrac{\alpha \pi}{\sin \alpha \pi}
\end{align*}
This expression is related to the generating function for Bernoulli polynomials, as we now establish.
Bernoulli polynomials
The generating function for the Bernoulli polynomials is
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\alpha e^{x \alpha}}{e^\alpha-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k (x) \frac{\alpha^k}{k!}  .
\end{align*}
We have
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\alpha e^{x \alpha}}{\sinh \frac{\alpha}{2}} = \dfrac{2\alpha e^{ \alpha ( x+\frac{1}{2} ) }}{e^\alpha-1} = 2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k (x+\frac{1}{2}) \frac{\alpha^k}{k!}
\end{align*}
We perform $\alpha \mapsto i 2 \pi \alpha$ and $x \mapsto x-\frac{1}{2}$,
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\pi \alpha}{\sin \pi \alpha} e^{i 2 \pi \alpha x - i \pi \alpha} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k (x) \frac{(i 2 \pi \alpha)^k}{k!}
\end{align*}
We recognise the LHS as our expression for $-I(\alpha)$. Taking the real part:
\begin{align*}
Re \dfrac{\pi \alpha}{\sin \pi \alpha} e^{i 2 \pi \alpha x - i \pi \alpha} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty B_{2k} (x) \frac{(-1)^k (2 \pi)^{2k}}{(2k)!} \alpha^{2k}
\end{align*}
Using this in $(**)$ we obtain the general formula:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^{2k}} & = \left. - \frac{1}{2 (2k)!} \dfrac{\partial^{2k}}{\partial \alpha^{2k}} Re \; e^{\alpha 2 \pi x i - \alpha \pi i} \dfrac{\alpha \pi}{\sin \alpha \pi} \right|_{\alpha=0}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{(-1)^{k+1} (2 \pi)^{2k}}{2 (2k)!} B_{2k} (x)
\end{align*}
For $k=1$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^2} = \pi^2 B_2 (x)  .
\end{align*}
We need to compute $B_2 (x)$. We next derive an explicit formula for Bernoulli polynomials.
Explicit formula for Bernoulli polynomials
The generating function for Bernoulli numbers is
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\alpha}{ e^\alpha - 1 } = \sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n \frac{\alpha^n}{n!}  .
\end{align*}
From the generating function for Bernoulli polynomials and Cauchy product of series:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n (x) \frac{\alpha^n}{n!} & = \dfrac{\alpha}{ e^\alpha - 1 } e^{\alpha x}
\nonumber \\
& = ( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k \alpha^k}{k!} ) ( \sum_{l=0}^\infty \frac{x^l \alpha^l}{l!} )
\nonumber \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!} B_{n-k} x^k \frac{\alpha^n}{n!}
\end{align*}
We read off
\begin{align*}
B_n (x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!} B_{n-k} x^k
\end{align*}
It is easy to expand the generating function for Bernoulli numbers to find $B_0=1$, $B_1 = -\frac{1}{2}$, and $B_3 = \frac{1}{6}$. Substituting them into the expression for $B_2 (x)$,
\begin{align*}
B_2 (x) & = B_0 + 2 B_1 x + B_2 x^2
\nonumber \\
& = x^2 - x + \frac{1}{6}  .
\end{align*}
So finally,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^2} = \pi^2 \left( x^2 - x - \frac{1}{6} \right)  .
\end{align*}
